# Is there a better way to pass optional parameters to methods in Scala?

Tags: scala

I have the following method

```
def myMethod(val overrideValue: Option[Boolean] = None): Int = {
    val myValue = overridenValue.getOrElse(getDefautValue())
    // do something else
}
```

If I want to use the default value I call the method like this
`myMethod()`

If I want to override the value I call the method like this `myMethod(Some(true))` or `myMethod(Some(false))`.

Is there a better way to do this where I can omit `Some(..)`

Comment: If you're using `Option` - then probably not. But you can just use a boolean instead and provide a boolean default value. Like `myMethod(doMoreWork: Boolean = False): Int = {}`. If user wants to override - they would pass value directly, if not - default is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the better way to save flexibility is use method overloading:

```
def myMethod: Int = {
  myMethod(getDefautValue())
}

def myMethod(argumentFlag: Boolean): Int = {
    // to do something with argumentFlag
}

def getDefautValue: Boolean = ???
```

here you can override getDefautValue, and you don't need to wrap you boolean argument into `Option`. But you can have some problems if your Boolean value can be `null`.